# LINQ to SQL query not returning correct DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to pull the most recent DateTime field from SQLite and it is returning the incorrect time.

Here's data in the database:

[image]

And here is my method to get the most recent DateTime via LINQ:

```
    public string getLastSyncTime()
    {
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
        {
            var query = db.Table<SyncAudit>()
                       .OrderByDescending(c => c.SyncTime)
                       .Select(c => c.SyncTime)
                       .FirstOrDefault();

          return query.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The issue is that it is not returning the expected datetime. I am getting 1/1/0001 12am:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: THis is the provider being used, per request: https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net

Edit 2: Requested SyncAudit Class:

```
class SyncAudit
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public DateTime SyncTime { get; set; }
    public int Successful { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You've said "LINQ to SQL" in the title - I thought LINQ to SQL only worked with SQL Server... what LINQ provider are you actually using?

Comment: do u have any row with syntime as null because the value coming is default datetime.min value

Comment: It looks like incorrect table or conn string. It can not find any record and return default value. Try First instead of FirstOrDefault and see if you we get error like sequence not contains element or something like this..

Comment: Using first() has the exact same result. And the entire content of  the database is the 4 rows listed above. No NULL values.

Comment: I'm grasping a straw here. Could the different formats have something to do with it?

Comment: What's the type of SyncType in DB? And could you add SyncAudit class to question?

Comment: @Chase I've added the SyncAudit class. The SyncTime column is DateTime.

Comment: @DavidTunnel change as public DateTime? synctime { get; set; } and try

Comment: can you check what is returning the whole query: db.Table<SyncAudit>().OrderByDescending(c => c.SyncTime).Select(c => c.SyncTime)

Comment: Can you try to select some other field from you table? Looks like the problem with the database connection - you are not connected and query returns default value for your datetime. Look at your db variable - bet it is not populated!

Comment: If you get a list of those objects are all the DateTimes 1/1/0001 12:00AM?

Answer (score 1):

Change

> public DateTime synctime{ get; set; }

to:

> public DateTime? synctime { get; set; }

Hope it will helps. What happens is DateTime is NOT NULL data type and it enforces to put a default value there (01/01/0001) to make sure that non-null date will be submitted.Don't know whether it can be an issue..try and check

Comment: This results in a compiling error in the getLastSyncTime() method. IT says there is now no definition for SyncTime.

Comment: @DavidTunnel in table that column may in notnull mode

Comment: @DavidTunnel when u created sqllite table did u define synctime column as notnull constraint

Comment: No,there were no special constrains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82978/discussion-between-sachu-and-david-tunnell).

Answer (score 1):

I looked at all possible scenarios when this result can happen. There is only one logical explanation to your problem. Your

```
db.Table<SyncAudit>()
```

is an empty collection and when you select

```
db.Table<SyncAudit>()
                   .OrderByDescending(c => c.SyncTime)
                   .Select(c => c.SyncTime)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

it will naturally return you default value of the DateTime.
Check your database connection and make sure it works first.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose what the problem is, go back to basics. Change the LINQ into a foreach loop to iterate over all the records, and find the biggest value. Now step through the code (because I suspect that won't do what you expect either) and you'll see what's going wrong. Then tell us what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I often have this issue using `Select` with `SQLite`. I don't know where the problem actually is, but it seems like lazy loading is broken so you end up getting default values when it comes time to evaluate the query. I solve this by forcing evaluation before the `Select`. It's annoying but it works:

Broken example (my own):

```
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(base.DatabasePath))
        {
            return db.Table<VideoUploadChunk>()
                .Where(c => c.VideoId == videoId)
                .Select(c => c.ChunkNumber)
                .ToList();
        }
```

This should return a list of `ints`, but it ends up returning a bunch of 0's (the default).

Fixed example:

```
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(base.DatabasePath))
        {
            var result = db.Table<VideoUploadChunk>()
                .Where(c => c.VideoId == videoId)
                .ToList();

            return result.Select(c => c.ChunkNumber);
        }
```

Your example (hopefully fixed):

```
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
    {
        var query = db.Table<SyncAudit>()
                   .OrderByDescending(c => c.SyncTime)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

        return query.Select(c => c.SyncTime).ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

SQLite [don't have special type for date and time](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), instead it use either number or text to store such data. `SQLiteConnection` constructor has a parameter `storeDateTimeAsTicks` which tell your provider how it should interpet and store date and time values. It is true by default.

So maybe `SyncTime` is stored in your database as a text rather than a number. Try to adjust connection so provider can [interpret data correctly](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L2365) by passing `false` as `storeDateTimeAsTicks`:

```
var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: false)
```